# pymongo sorting by date

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to get newest posts first, and try the following:

```
db.posts.find({"date": {"$lt": tomorrow, "$gte": 
               today}}).sort({'date':pymongo.DESCENDING})
```

(without **sort**, I get the oldest posts first fine)

I am getting this error

```
TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list
```

What is going on here? Is not it possible to sort by date?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is not the correct format of parameters for the `sort` function. The correct syntax would look something like this:

```
db.posts.find(...).sort('date',pymongo.DESCENDING)
```

Here is a link to the relevant documentation for the `sort` function:
http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.sort

To sort by multiple parameters you can use the following syntax:

```
db.posts.find(...).sort([
  ('date', pymongo.ASCENDING),
  ('other_field', pymongo.DESCENDING)
]):
```

Answer (score 8):

In PyMongo you can try also this if there is an error for .sort('date', pymongo.DESCENDING)

```
db.posts.find().sort('date', -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this in Flask and PyMongo.

```
import datetime
```

the sort function:

```
def sort_data_by_dates(data):
    return datetime.strptime(data['created'], '%d-%m-%Y %I:%M')
```

the actual view and function:

```
@app.route("/data", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def get_data:
    data = list(db.posts.find())
    sorted_data = sorted(data, key=sort_prospect_by_dates, reverse=True)
```